# fuzzy decission making

Tags: algorithms, ranking, decision-theory, fuzzy, decision-rule

I'm working on decision-making using Double Hierarchy Fuzzy Linguistic terms. I want to ask if can we compare two Double Hierarchy Fuzzy Linguistic terms.
I am trying to implement the TODIM algorithm for ranking.